# Proof concerning preservation of negative eigenvalues under matrix addition of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetry

I've been working on this proof from a test review for about an hour and a half trying to figure out what to do. I have also scoured the internet in an attempt to find a similar problem to hint at where I should be going. I'm in an elementary level linear algebra course.

The proof reads: Let A and B be symmetric real n × n matrices with all negative eigenvalues. Prove that the matrix C = A + B also has negative eigenvalues.

I have tried looking at the matrices A, B, and C as an equation in spectral decomposition form and in a form of orthogonal diagonalization and I must be missing something obvious or going about it in the wrong way. In my head, I can kinda get the picture of what's going on, but I can't find the theorems and the words to describe it. Help of any form appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory)? Because that is what I would use here.

Comment: We've not gone over it in class... I can look it up though :) Thanks

Comment: I guess the matrices are real ones, right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Ok, then the answer holds, otherwise we would need $A,B$ to be Hermitian ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since $A,B$ are real symmetric matrices, this means they are [negative definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Negative-definite), since all their eigenvalues are negative. We claim that $A+B$ is a negative definite matrix, as well. We can do so by following the definition. For every vector $x$...